# PHP caching including css

Tags: php, caching

Im using this code for caching my data:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.php';
$cachetime = 3600;

if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
  include($cachefile); //include cache file
}else{
  ob_start(); //start output buffering
?>

<?php

....

echo '<div class="profile-font2">', $items, '</div>';

   $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w'); //open cache file
  fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); //create new cache file
  fclose($fp); //close cache file
  ob_end_flush(); //flush output buffered
}
?>
```

The echo output get stored in the file. But I´ve a problem with my styles. The `<div class="">` or `table class` gets ignored. So I just get the naked data. How is it possible that my styles get considered?

Comment: Where are your styles defined? Are they in the head? Are they separate files?

Comment: The styles are in one separate css.

Comment: considering the number of cache engines that exist, why build your own

Comment: If the style is being referenced in the head of the html output, I see no reason why your css would suddenly die if php is regurgitating a cache of its output, vs building it new (with any caching library or your own). So I am going to guess theres something more going on here than we are shown.

Comment: @rtfm considering the number of childrens in the world that exist, why make your own?

Comment: @dognose agreed, i have none. and never will.

Comment: @rtfm then let those, who are willing to create some, create their own :-) - If we would always rely on "existing" stuff, there would be no improvement overall.

Comment: I would rather they didn't, the world is overpopulated. Dont Reinventing the wheel

Comment: @rtfm haha, different topic, please see http://childoverflow.com :)

Comment: @rtfm But I disagree to "don't reinvent the wheel"! **if you stop getting better, you stop being good!**

Comment: Did you write the OS your using? or browser or IDE? build your own car? make your own clothes? .... do you honestly code with out using any frameworks or libraries built by others.

Comment: @rtfm I wrote my companies ERP-System, despite the fact there are thousands of systems out there. It matches all our needs without a single  inconvenience or limitation.

Comment: @rtfm and yes, ofc. I use frameworks or libraries available. However sometimes they don't *exactly* provide what's needed - then I'll do it from the scratch.

Just saying that "starting from the scratch" isn't always a bad thing. It helps innovations taking place, but also helps people "learning" how things are done. (Using `commons-io` is easy, but everyone should have used *plain* IO-Access at least once...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo '<div class="profile-font2">'` - here you are just creating a div - it has a class-attribute, yes - but since you don't include any stylesheet - that means the class-attribute is worthless.

So, it depends on what you want to achive:

- do you want to render the (cached) content according to the latest stylesheet?
- do you want to cache the style-sheet as well?

For the first example, it would be quite easy, cause you just need to include the actual style-sheet before printing the cached content, i.e.:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<?include("cachedContent.extension")?>
</body>
```

The second example would be more tricky, cause you need to "align" all the cached style-sheets with their respective HTML-File. I don't think that's trivial and hence don't have an answer for that case.

Comment: There was some error with my css file in the head. Thanks.